# How to serialize generic list in asp.net so that jQuery DataTables can accept it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datatables

Lets say I have set up things like this:

**narudzbe.aspx.cs**

```
[WebMethod]
public static string getAllPartnere(int kid)
{
 string json = string.Empty;
 List<stp_WEB_MP_PARTNERI_GetPartneriDDList_Result> partnerList = new List<stp_WEB_MP_PARTNERI_GetPartneriDDList_Result>();
 partnerList = DANarudzbe.GetPartnerList(kid);
 json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(partnerList, new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter());
 return json;
}
```

**narudzbe.aspx** - javascript

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Narudzbe/narudzbe.aspx/getAllPartnere",
    data: '{kid:"' + Partner_ID + '"}',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (msg) {
        $('#partneri').DataTable({
    data: msg.d,
    columns: [
        { title: "PartnerID" },
        { title: "Naziv" }
    ]
});
}                    
});
```

**narudzbe.aspx** - html

```
...
<table class="display dataTable" id="partneri"></table>
...
```

I need to know how to use json.net to serialize generic list so that all values are enclosed in quotation marks so that returned list is serialized so that data tables are able to read it.

Serialized list does not have numerical values in quotation marks when serialized like I did so datatables gets some of " quotation marks recognized as values.

I also need to state that this is the first time that I'm using datatables and am not a developer so take it easy on me.

Well to be honest I want to know also if this is the correct way to use in datatables with ajax and server processing or is there easier and more simplistic way.

Comment: try this link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8ef97c/web-service-in-Asp-Net-part-4 , this one has good tutorial.

Comment: @KishoreSahas - Thank you ... but I think you misunderstood my question. I already know how to serialize a generic list or a object. What I want to know is what must I do to serialize a list or object in a way that all values are treated as strings and are in quotation marks. I am under the impression that this is needed so jquery datatables are able to draw the information. I concluded this after going trough many examples in their documentation and more ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you have a problem with your numeric values as they are serialized correctly, as numeric values and that is the default behaviour. You can check that there is no problem with it in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f3cmbmxo/)
Check first ten rows, there are only integer values, displayed correctly.

However, to answer your question.
There is no converter or some other simple way to say json.net how to convert your numeric into string (like there is for date, or enum like from your own example). 
You would have to write your own converter like it is shown [here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm).
But that looks like an overhead.

If your original class is not that big I would create a copy of it with all string properties in it.

```
public class SerializablePartner
{
    public string PartnerId { get; set; }
    public string Naziv { get; set; }
    // your other properties
    public SerializablePartner(stp_WEB_MP_PARTNERI_GetPartneriDDList_Result originalItem)
    {
        // map your values here 
        this.PartnerId = originalItem.PartnerId.ToString();
        this.Naziv = originalItem.Naziv; // already a string, no need for change
        // your other properties
    }
}
```

That way all your properties will be for sure enclosed in double quotes as for json.net they are strings.
And of course your original 
**partnerList**
would have to be converted to List<SerializablePartnerList> prior to doing json conversion.
Something like this:

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(partnerList.Select(partner => new SerializablePartner(partner)).ToList());
```

Comment: It seams I was too preocupied with serialization that it didn't even occur to me to test my own theory. Thank you. As for json.net I had the same idea a moment ago but found it not so practical and so have not tried it. Thank you, this was already a big help.